# G'MIC と system32\cmd.exe について

Tags: 画像

G'MIC のフィルタを試したら、コマンドプロンプトが一瞬起動して(system32\cmd.exeと書いていたような気がします)すぐに消えることがあるのですが、正常な動作ですか？

**環境**
・Windows10
・GIMP 2.10.12
・G'MIC Qt for GIMP 2.10 Windows 64 bits

**気になる点**
・幾つかのフィルタを試すと、コマンドプロンプトが一瞬起動してすぐに消えました
・幾つかのフィルタを試すと、プラグインがクラッシュして落ちました
・幾つかのフィルタを試すと、プレビューエラーと表示されました
・幾つかのフィルタを試すと、プラグインエラーと表示されました

---

**質問**
Q1.G'MICのフィルタ実行すると、cmd.exe起動する(ことがある)のは正常な挙動ですか？

```
 G'MICは画像処理演算子とパイプラインの設計に専用の軽量だが強力なスクリプト言語 （ G'MIC言語 ）を定義します。
```

Q2.フィルタのメンテナンスについて
使用可能なフィルタ数として500件以上表示されているのですが、このフィルタはメンテナンスされていると考えられますか？
以前に追加されたフィルタだから(バージョン間差異のため)単に動作しないだけなのか、それとも誰でも簡単にスクリプトを仕込めるようなフローになっているので気をつけた方が良いか、知りたいです…

Answer (score 0):

GIMP自体はGUIのアプリですが、G'MICやScript-Fuはコマンドラインで動作する**スクリプト言語**です。
Windows環境で実行した場合にコマンドプロンプトが表示されるのは正常な動作のうちだと思います。